# How can i place my 2 divs beside each other?

Tags: html, css, css-position

**How can i position that the blue and black div stays beside each other, and not above ??
i want the black div at left corner with some padding, and the blue div right beside of it**

```css
#sortboks {
 align-content: center;
 color: white;
 max-width: 8%;
 padding: 1%;
 left: 10%;
 background-color: blue;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 15px;
 box-shadow:0;
   
}
#hvidboks {
 align-content: center;
 color: white;
 max-width: 20%;
 padding: 1%;
 left: 20%;
 background-color: #000000;
 position:relative;
 font-size: 15px;
 box-shadow:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sortboks"> 
  <p> 
    <strong>NAME: </strong>
    <br><strong>NICK NAME:</strong>  
    <br><strong>AGE:</strong> 
    <br><strong>BIRTH:</strong>
    <br><strong>CITY:</strong>  
    <br><strong>EDUCATION:</strong>  
    <br><strong>LANGUAGE:</strong> 
    <br><strong>MOTTO:</strong>  
    <br><strong>FAV.QUOTES:</strong>  
    <br><strong>CODE EXPERIENCE:</strong> 
  </p>
</div>

<div id="hvidboks" style="width: 300px; top: 0px;bottom: 0px; "> 
  <p> 
    <br>  
    <br> 22 Year 
    <br> 11-08-1994
    <br> Kolding 
    <br> Multimediadesigner
    <br> Danish - English - Persian - Dari
    <br> If you have a dream you gotta protect it no matter what
    <br> Dont talk the talk, walk the walk
    <br> HTML - CSS
  </p>
</div>
```

what can you guys recommend ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ;) please check my answer. if i solved your issue, mark as the right answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a wrapper with "display: flex" like i did here: 
(you have to add your padding by your self, its only an example to show how to get them in one line)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
#sortboks {
 align-content: center;
 color: white;
 max-width: 8%;
 padding: 1%;
 background-color: blue;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 15px;
 box-shadow:0;
   
}
#hvidboks {
 align-content: center;
 color: white;
 max-width: 20%;
 padding: 1%;
 background-color: #000000;
 position:relative;
 font-size: 15px;
 box-shadow:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="sortboks"> 
    <p> 
      <strong>NAME: </strong>
      <br><strong>NICK NAME:</strong>  
      <br><strong>AGE:</strong> 
      <br><strong>BIRTH:</strong>
      <br><strong>CITY:</strong>  
      <br><strong>EDUCATION:</strong>  
      <br><strong>LANGUAGE:</strong> 
      <br><strong>MOTTO:</strong>  
      <br><strong>FAV.QUOTES:</strong>  
      <br><strong>CODE EXPERIENCE:</strong> 
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="hvidboks" style="width: 300px; top: 0px;bottom: 0px; "> 
    <p> 

      <br>  
      <br> 22 Year 
      <br> 11-08-1994
      <br> Kolding 
      <br> Multimediadesigner
      <br> Danish - English - Persian - Dari
      <br> If you have a dream you gotta protect it no matter what
      <br> Dont talk the talk, walk the walk
      <br> HTML - CSS
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

> If you want to learn more about CSS try Codecademy. Its free!
>   https://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: it still dosen't work, with the new Edited code you been postin :/ ?

Comment: note that i removed the "left" attributes of your css. if you click on run code, you can see that its working. ;)

Comment: you're welcome. please mark as the right answer. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers